# My app use memory over 50MB

Tags: android, memory

I'm a Japanese Android Developer.I have been developing an app, but I have a problem.

My app have two activity. First is Launch Activity, and second is TopPage.
Launch have only one image view (set resource in xml). TopPage have two webview for Ad and 20 imagebutton(set resource in xml).

The problem is my app use memory over 50MB. I made sure the memory usage of my app in the eclipse with DDMS. Result, Heap is 45MB, Allocated 32MB, Used 73%. 
But, we have another way to know the usage of app, that is "settings" on Android OS.
I confirmed with that, the usage is 50MB over.

I thought that image resources remains in memory, so I tried this code

```
public static final void cleanUpView(final View view){
if(view instanceof ImageButton){
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)view;
        ib.setImageDrawable(null);
        button++;
    }else if(view instanceof ImageView){
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)view;
        iv.setImageDrawable(null);
        image++;
    }else if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)view;
        int size = vg.getChildCount();
        for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            cleanUpView(vg.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
```

}

but I could not solve that.

If you know anything about it, please advice.

Thank you.

Comment: how is that a problem ?

Comment: What are the sizes of your images in pixel units?

Comment: @user2952027 nobody cares if you are a Japanese developer.

Answer (score 0):

downscale your bitmaps.. Theres no way you should be using that much memory unless you are plugging in raw giant bitmaps into these image buttons.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Also kitkat added memory tools.
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html